# JSON object to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, json

I want to know what is the fastest function that can be used to convert a json object into a java script array here an example

```
var j = '[{"var1":"val1", "var2":"val2"}]';

var arr  ===> [var1] = "val1"
```

The bottom line is to avoid for loops as much as possible

Comment: You got a JSON string, not a JSON "object".

Comment: For future reference: In JavaScript there is no associative array. So using `someObject[key]=value;` the someObject be any Object `{}`. It can be an Array since Array is an Object and can have other properties assigned to it with `someArray[key]=value` but there is no need for it to be an Array. What you wanted to do is have Object A.key take the values of Object B.key where B is the first element in an array created with JSSON.parse You could do this with `var configObj={};...obj=JSON.parse(config)[0];for (var k in obj){ configObj[k]=obj[k];}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern browsers will support the native [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function.

```
var arr = JSON.parse('[{"var1":"val1", "var2":"val2"}]');

console.log(arr);

//Just to be clear for OP
console.log(Array.isArray(arr)); //true
```

> I want the output to be Arr[var1] = "val1"] not [Object]

That means you want to object at index 0 in the array.

```
var obj = JSON.parse('[{"var1":"val1", "var2":"val2"}]')[0];

console.log(obj['var1']); //val1
```

If you only want the values:

```
var values = JSON.parse('[{"var1":"val1", "var2":"val2"}]').reduce(function (values, obj) {
    for (var k in obj) values.push(obj[k]);
    return values;
}, []);

console.log(values); //["val1", "val2"]
```

Comment: Yes, every browser since IE8 knows `JSON.parse`: http://caniuse.com/json

Comment: I think the return of JSON.parse is Object not array, I want the return to be array type not Object

Comment: An Array is an Object in JavaScript. So the answer will work just fine.

Comment: That's because your input object is an array with a single item (ie object) in it.

Comment: I want the output to be Arr[var1] = "val1"] not 

[Object] var1: "val1"

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa The return value is an `Array`, however `typeof arr` will be `object` if that's what you are looking at.

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa I.e. you **don't** want the array but the contained object?? `var arr = JSON.parse(…)[0]`.

Comment: @kay exactly I want the contents of the object to merged into the array

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa you want the result to be an array (as in `arr.__proto__ === Array`), but it should have the keys of `arr[0]` to be merged into `arr`?

Comment: @plalx I think your solution can work, but it takes only values neglecting the keys. when I applied the code you provided it just neglected var1 as the key. I need both the key and the value I am trying to access them both. I have some trials to do

Comment: it just worked, thanks a lot I got now the key and the value and merged them into another array perfectly. do you have tips about its performance. I am still searching about some of the functions you used

Comment: This is the case I have been working on, I wanted to make TinyMCE works as EmberJS component so when I pass configurations through JSON TinyMCE is shown correctly. 

You can see a working example on http://jsbin.com/aRiPUkE/1/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `JSON.parse`.

```
var json = '[{"var1": "val1", "var2": "val2"}]';
var arr = JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use jQuery, though that might no longer be preferred.

```
var j = '[{"var1":"val1", "var2":"val2"}]';
var arr = jQuery.parseJSON( j );
```

This should work well in some older browsers if you need that kind of thing of course.